Which aspects of RF emission were TI unable to get under control?
The TI 99/4 (as opposed to 4A) was a computer killed by RF emission problems. From Wikipedia

Through the development period, several companies attempting to enter the home computer market were faced with significant pushback from the Federal Communications Commission (FCC). The FCC had developed new rules for consumer devices that connected directly to televisions in an effort to control ongoing complaints about interference by poorly shielded devices. Televisions of the era generally had only a single antenna input, and thus connecting to them required the internal video signal of the device to be converted to radio frequency using an RF modulator. The resulting signals were often poorly shielded and signal leakage could be picked up in the antennas of nearby televisions.[18]


The new rules were extremely difficult to meet. TI continued battling the FCC both in the lab and in Congress, where it had considerable power due to its position within Texas's high-tech industry. It failed to meet the FCC requirements as the release date approached. The company eventually gave up and bundled a modified Zenith Electronics television as a computer monitor, eliminating the need for the RF modulator that generates the interference by connecting directly to the TV's circuitry using a composite video signal. This put the introductory price at US$1,150 (equivalent to $4,253 in 2023).[19]


The 99/4 sold poorly. Very little software was available, as few developers ported their products to its 16-bit CPU.[20] The machine was met with almost universal disdain when it was released. Every review complained about the keyboard, the lack of lower case characters, any sort of expansion, and lack of software. In July 1980, Adam Osborne reported that, despite poor sales, TI had raised the price of a complete system to $1,400, higher than the popular Apple II, which started at $950. Osborne said, "Some dealers, who have offered the complete system (including the monitor) for less than the price of the Apple, have still been unable to sell it".[21] TI sold fewer than 20,000 computers by summer 1981, less than one tenth Apple or Radio Shack's volume. Atari, Inc. had an installed base of Atari 8-bit computers more than twice as large.[22] David H. Ahl described the 99/4 as "vastly overpriced, particularly considering its strange keyboard, non-standard Basic, and lack of software".[5] The Times called it an "embarrassing failure".[23]

Admittedly, the direct complaints refer to things like the cheap keyboard, but the Atari 400 had an even worse keyboard, with fewer complaints. The problem was that by failing the FCC requirements, the TI 99/4 condemned itself to having to supply its own monitor, therefore putting itself into the 'serious computer' rather than 'toy computer' price bracket, and being judged as a serious computer.
(In 1981, the allowed emission level was relaxed, and the TI 99/4A was introduced, only to be killed by a price war with Commodore, but that's another story.)
The failure of the 99/4 to meet the FCC requirements was not for lack of trying. As Wikipedia points out, they really did try.
It's also not for lack of physical possibility. The Atari 2600 proved that by successfully meeting the requirements. It's fundamentally the same kind of device: a CPU and some memory that need to be wrapped in metal, a cartridge slot and handful of other connectors, an RF modulator.
But it seems to have been very difficult, sufficiently so that Atari pulled it off but TI didn't.
Is it possible to say, either on the basis of documents written at the time, later interviews with participants, or just by applying domain knowledge to the problem and the available resources at the time, exactly how/why the 99/4 was persistently emitting too much RF interference? Was there a relevant difference between it and the 2600, did Atari stumble on the correct approaches where TI did not, or some other reason for the different outcome?

I remember on a lot of devices, the video can still be received by the TV even if the RF cable is disconnected.

There was a family my mom knew where the living room tv on the other side of the wall could watch the games played on the NES in the sons room (in noisy B&W) if tuned to Ch 3
